# Is $C^\infty(\Omega)$ contained in $L^2(\Omega)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded open connected set in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Is the set $C^\infty(\Omega)$ contained in $L^2(\Omega)$, i.e. $C^\infty(\Omega)\subseteq L^2(\Omega)$?

My reasoning is that any function in $C^\infty(\Omega)$, after squaring is still in $C^\infty(\Omega)$ and thus integrable. Is there any loophole in the above reasoning?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Your proof relies on the (wrong) argument that $C^\infty(\Omega)\subset L^1(\Omega)$, when you say _any function in $C^\infty(\Omega)$, after squaring is still in $C^\infty(\Omega)$ and thus integrable._ The only this you can say is that any function of class $C^\infty$ on $\Omega$ is measurable (hence _locally_ integrable), but that's all. In fact, your result is wrong, see Carl Christian's answer below for a counter-example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a problem at the boundary. Take $\Omega = (0,1)$ and $f(x)=x^{-1}$.

Comment: This also shows a function in $C^\infty(\Omega)$ might fail to belong to be integrable.

Comment: Thanks for this excellent example

Comment: Yoyostein: You are very welcome. @Gerw: Good point, thanks.